# SSAS Daily Calculation Rolled up to Any Dimension

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube

Im trying to create a daily calculation in my Cube or an MDX statement that will do a calculation daily and roll up to any dimension.  I've been able to successfully get the values back, however the performance is not what I think it should be.

My fact table will have 4 dimensions 1 of which being daily date (time).  I have a formula that uses 4 other measures in this fact table and those need to be calculated daily and then geometrically linked across the time dimension.

The following MDX statement works great and produces the correct value but it is very slow.  I have tried using exp(sum(log+1))-1 and multiply seems to perform a little better but not good enough.  Is there another approach to this solution or is there something wrong with my MDX statement?

I have tried defining aggregations For [Calendar_Date] and [Dim_Y].[Y ID], but it does not seem to use these aggregations.

```
WITH
   MEMBER Measures.MyCustomCalc AS (
   (
      Measures.x -Measures.y
    ) -
    (
      Measures.z - Measures.j
    )
)
/
Measures.x

MEMBER Measures.LinkedCalc AS ASSP.MULTIPLY(
   [Dim_Date].[Calendar Date].Members,
   Measures.MyCustomCalc + 1
) - 1
SELECT
Measures.LinkedCalc ON Columns,
[Dim_Y].[Y ID].Members ON Rows
FROM
[My DB]
```

The above query takes 7 seconds to run w/ the following number of records:

Measure: 98,160 records
Dim_Date: 5,479 records
Dim_Y: 42 records

We have assumed that by defining an aggregation that the amount of calculations we'd be performing would only be 42 * number of days, in this case a maximum of 5479 records.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any reason this can't be added as a custom calculation? That way at least some of the work could be done at cube processing time.

Comment: Thanks Bill.  We tried creating a calculation.  We did not try creating a MeasureExpression - is this what you were thinking?  The first option yielded no performance gains.  In doing some research with looking the fields that need aggregation, it appears that Calendar Date always pops up.  However, we've tried creating aggregations on every dimension by calendar date.  Thanks for your time!